# javascript to swap content on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, swap

here is the jsfiddle of what im trying to accomplish.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=08LnngLQ1M

im trying to make the content in an html file swap in and out. The java script file is set up to apply the slide function to my div. Please show me what I need to add to the javascript in order to allow the information to swap in and out as well as display appropriately.

first my javascript file then under is the index.html file. also displayed the css in the head in order to show how i am trying to hide the content.

please show me how to implement the javascript i am lacking and then make appropriate changes to my html and css if necessary.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
>   var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
>   var href = $('#navigationMenu li a').each(function(){
>       var href = $(this).attr('href');
>       if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
>           var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
>           $('#content').load(toLoad)
>       }                                           
>   });
>
>   $('#navigationMenu li a').click(function(){
>
>       var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
>       $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
>       $('#load').remove();
>       $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
>       $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
>       window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
>
>
>       function loadContent() {
>           $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
>       }
>
>       function showNewContent() {
>           $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
>       }
>
>       function hideLoader() {
>           $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
>       }
>       return false;
>
>
>
>   });
>
> });
>
>
>
>
>
>     <style type="text/css">
>     #page1, #page2, #page3, #page4, #page5 {
>       display: none;
>       overflow:hidden;
>     }
>     </style>
>
>
>     </head>
>
>     <body>
>     <div id="top">
>     </div>
>
>
>     <!-- The navigation css is in styles.css -->
>
>     <div id="main">
>
>     <ul id="navigationMenu">
>         <li>
>           <a class="home" href="#home">
>                 <span>Home</span>
>             </a>
>         </li>
>
>         <li>
>           <a class="about" href="#about">
>                 <span>About</span>
>             </a>
>         </li>
>
>         <li>
>            <a class="services" href="#services">
>                 <span>Services</span>
>              </a>
>         </li>
>
>         <li>
>           <a class="portfolio" href="#portfolio">
>                 <span>Portfolio</span>
>             </a>
>         </li>
>
>         <li>
>           <a class="contact" href="#contact">
>                 <span>Contact us</span>
>             </a>
>         </li>
>     </ul>
>
>     </div>
>
>
>     <!-- The css for the main area is in css.css-->
>     <!-- The wrapper and the content div control the jquery slide up effect -->
>     <div id="wrapper">
>       <div id="content">
>
>         <!-- The 5 pages content divs will display in this area -->           
>
>       </div>
>     </div> 
>
>     <!-- The actual content I want to switch in and out of the panel, this is hidden -->
>      <div id="page1" class="pages">
>      <p>1 Whole bunch of text 1</div>
>
>      <div id="page2" class="pages">
>      <p>2 Whole bunch of text 2</div>
>
>      <div id="page3" class="pages">
>      <p>3 Whole bunch of text 3</div>
>
>      <div id="page4" class="pages">
>      <p>4 Whole bunch of text 4</div>
>
>      <div id="page5" class="pages">
>      <p>5 Whole bunch of text 5</div>
> ```

Comment: Why don't the `id` attributes of your content divs match the `href` attributes of the links that are supposed to open them? Shouldn't `id="page1"` actually be `id="home"`, and so forth?

Comment: because in the css i have the class set up for the navigation bar. so thats why i have the div id set up as page 1 2 etc.

Comment: But when you click a link, say the `href="#home"` link, how do you know which of the hidden pages to navigate to? You need some way to relate each link to its associated content - there are several ways you could do that, but giving the hidden divs `id="home"`, `id="about"` and so forth is the most obvious way...

Comment: i have not defined the javascript in order to accomplish that. that is what i need help with. i added a separate class to each div at the bottom of the html document so it could be located with the java script. so each div is page1 page 2 page3 etc and then the class attached to all five divs is called pages

Comment: So _again,_ when you click `href=#home` which div is it supposed to open?

Comment: from the examples i have seen it looks like i should be able to assign the div holding the navigation to GET each of the div selectors called on by class or the div id. I am obviously not understanding this so if you have a better suggestion please do tell! :) feel free to check out the jsfiddle link at the top of my post.

Comment: when you click the home link i would like for page1 to open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you change your html so that your "pages" have ids that actually correspond to the href of the associated menu items:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>

...
<div id="home" class="pages"><p>1 Whole bunch of text 1</p></div>
```

Then you can implement your slide animation paging thing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navigationMenu a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = this.href.split("#")[1];
        $("#content").slideUp(function() {
            $(this).empty()
                   .append($("#" + item).clone().show())
                   .slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

Note that there is no need to use `.load()` because you have all of the content already on the page. You can just empty the container and then append a clone of the relevant content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FtS8u/1/

Or in my opinion a neater option would be to move all of the content into the `#content` div to start with, show the `#home` "page" by default, and then just hide and show the pages in place:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#navigationMenu a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = this.href.split("#")[1];
        $(".pages:visible").slideUp(function () {
            $("#" + item).slideDown();
        });
    });
    $("#home").show();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FtS8u/2/

And a last thing to consider: if you remove the `.pages { display : none; }` CSS and instead use jQuery to hide the pages by adding this to the start of your document ready:

```
$(".pages").hide();
```

Then you'll still get the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/FtS8u/7/ - except that if the user happens to have JavaScript disabled the page will still work because then the default anchor navigation will jump down to the associated div: http://jsfiddle.net/FtS8u/8/

Comment: I just want you to know when I am going to name my first born after you. Its name will be nnnnn. Thank you so much you are my hero. this took me twelve hours 3 forums and a whole bunch of nonsense answers and tutorials all to get to you! woo hoo! thanks!

Comment: I was literally about to ask you how to do it that way and you beat me to the punch! thanks again man!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry about the extra edit: in my last example I kept slightly messing up the html in the fiddle so I ended up updating it a lot of times. Anyway, if you name your firstborn after me remember it is "nnnnnn" with _six_ n's.

Comment: I think im missing something here... I am trying to make this work with all the information in the same content div just hiding and showing like you said. but when i change to the jsfiddle its not working for me... the content is just hidden all the time. except the first div onload but once i click a link it wont come back

Comment: The one I originally posted for that solution (http://jsfiddle.net/FtS8u/2/) works fine for me - tested in Chrome only...

Comment: ahhhhh man i got it... thanks bro i was just being a tard with the .js... your the best six n's it is!!!! lol